# Quiero hacer un SendKeys de un ENTER con JavaScript a un campo de texto de un formulario HTML

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Estoy tratando de enviar un ENTER en el campo de texto "nombrecompleto" a través de un envío de teclas del teclado, es decir un SendKeys. No logro saber como hacerlo. Agradecería vuestra ayuda.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="formBasico">
        <p>Ingresa tu nombre completo: <input type="text" name="nombrecompleto"></p> 
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar la información">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes crear un pequeño script con JavaScript que haga esa función,
Aquí te dejo un ejemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="formBasico">
        <p>Ingresa tu nombre completo: <input type="text" name="nombrecompleto"></p> 
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar la información">
    </form>

    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            var campoTexto = document.querySelector('input[name="nombrecompleto"]');

            var eventoTeclado = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
                key: 'Enter'
            });

            campoTexto.dispatchEvent(eventoTeclado);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```